# Group by column and order by one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having Student table consists of column sectionId `(foreign key)`, Name and RollNoInClass. Now I'm selecting the students by using this query

```
SELECT Name, RollNoInClass, sectionId FROM students GROUP BY SectionId, Name, RollNoInClass ORDER BY RollNoInClass
```

[image: result]

[image: expected]

But I need like this

How to achieve this by query

Comment: what's wrong with what you did? Can you post eht query and the error you got?

Comment: update your question add  sample in tabular text  .. and add  alos the expected  result  .. don't use image only

Comment: How about spending one more minute and paste the "data" instead of screenshot.

Comment: you've answered how to do it in the title of the post

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I just asked the query to get like above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
SELECT Name, RollNo
FROM [StudentsTableName]
GROUP BY SectionId, Name, RollNo
ORDER BY RollNo
```

Comment: I've tried already. I'll get result as order by RollNo only

Comment: Change the last line to do ORDER BY SectionId, RollNo

Comment: `SELECT RollNoInClass, StudentId, sectionID, Name from students group by sectionId, RollNoInClass order by SectionId, RollNoInClass` this is working. Anyway thanks for your answer